# Python Requests: able to login then access auth-restricted page, but cannot POST to page

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I want to build a simple Python app that changes the names of my meals on MyFitnessPal. I can login to MyFitnessPal at https://myfitnesspal.com/account/login. Once logged in, I can access my diary settings page where I can update the names of my meals using a form.

My app can log in and successfully request the diary settings page via a GET request. However, my app cannot successfully POST to the diary settings page to update my meal name. I have read every bit of documentation I can find and this question is quite difficult to answer alone. I would appreciate your help tackling this issue so I may further my understanding.

Code, with healthy comments, pasted below:

```
# standard library
from time import sleep
from random import uniform

# third party packages
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class MFP():

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

        # url for website
        self.base_url = 'https://www.myfitnesspal.com'

        # login action
        self.login_url = 'https://www.myfitnesspal.com/account/login'

        # page that contains diary information we want to update
        self.diary_url = 'https://www.myfitnesspal.com/account/diary_settings'

        # Firefox
        self.headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; rv:2.2) Gecko/20110201'
        }

        # establish persistent session across class
        self.session = requests.Session()

    def login(self):

        # grab the session
        s = self.session

        # visit the login url via GET so we can soup it for the access token
        base = s.get(self.login_url)

        # soup the response to the login URL GET request to scrape the token
        soup = BeautifulSoup(base.content, "html.parser")
        token = soup.find('input', attrs={'name': 'authenticity_token'})['value']

        # add token to headers for continued authentication
        self.headers.update({'authenticity_token': token})

        # sleep for a moment before logging in
        sleep(uniform(.55,1.4))

        # login to MFP
        login = s.post(self.login_url, headers=self.headers, verify=True,
            data={'username': self.username, 'password': self.password})

        # access the diary settings page
        diary = s.get(self.diary_url, verify=True, headers=self.headers)

        # soup the webpage with bs4
        soup = BeautifulSoup(diary.content, "html.parser")

        # grab the name of my first meal to see if this actually works
        # found the key 'mean_names[0][description]' via 'view page source' on browser
        meal0=soup.find('input', {'name': 'meal_names[0][description]'
            }).get('value')
        # print meal to visually check it's right (it is)
        print(meal0)

        # Great, we're in, now let's wait again so our request isn't ignored
        sleep(uniform(.55,1.4))

        # Attempt to update the name of the first meal via POST method to
        # see if we can actually change it.
        diary_post=s.post(self.diary_url, headers=self.headers, verify=True,
            data={'meal_names[0][description]': 'updated meal 0 test name'})

        # this does not work, refreshing the webpage shows that
        # the mealnames are unchanged. However, the status code is 200.

        # Why is POST ineffective? Let's see what the response looks like
        soup = BeautifulSoup(diary_post.content, "html.parser")
        print(soup)

        # It prints the login page! Our session ended?
        # Why does this post method not work? It seems like I've done everything right.
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably lost the session cookie.

Logins usually rely on cookies.

Also, the web site may have some countermeasures against illegal web scraping. Check the terms of service: most sites disallow the use of such automated accesses. Terminating suspicious sessions would be common to do.

Comment: Have you checked - eg via the networks tab in chrome - if that really is how the site does a POST?

Comment: @jlaur: yes, I have checked. Not sure if any specific output would help to verify, but the networks tab, subtab "HTML" shows a POST method with a 302 status via the proper URL, diary_settings